# Writing quality data models in OOP

Tags: php, oop

I am stuck trying to write good data models for my application. Let's take persons as an example of data. How would I make a non-repeatable, but reusable separation of a `Person` class, as opposed to the `People` class? It seems utterly wrong to have to define table (and their joined tables) twice, for both classes.

```
class Person extends CommonModel {
   protected static $table = 'people';
   protected static $join  = array('city' => 'city.id = people.city_id');

   public function __construct($id) {
      // Initialize stuff
   }

   public function fetch($id) {
      // Return person with id $id
   }

   public function isVeryTall() {
      // Return boolean
   }
}

class People extends CommonModel {
   protected static $table = 'people';
   protected static $join  = array('city' => 'city.id = people.city_id');

   public function __construct($id) {
      // Initialize stuff
   }

   public function fetch() {
      // Return all persons
   }
}
```

But if I join them into a single class, then it won't make sense that some methods, which only make sense in a context of a single person, will be available when a list of people is returned. For example, the `isVeryTall()` method only really works if I invoke it on an object that represents one person. But if I had called the `fetchPeople()` method, then my `isVeryTall()` method will be available in the returned object, and it will have no sense (actually it probably wouldn't even work correctly).

```
class Person extends CommonModel {

   protected static $table = 'people';
   protected static $join  = array('city' => 'city.id = people.city_id');

   public function __construct($id) {
      // Return one person
   }

   public function fetchPeople() {
      // Returns all people 
   }

   public function isVeryTall() {
      // Return boolean
   }
}
```

And another question is, how do I implement the method that returns a list of people, to return objects of people, instead of just arrays? Would I manually have to loop through all the rows and then instantiate them into objects?

```
public function fetchPeople() {
   $people = $this->fetchAll();
   foreach($people as $id => $person) {
      $people[$id] = new Person($person);
   }
   return $people;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't put implementation-specific persistence code (your database stuff) in your domain classes. Keep them separate. Then you can have a Person class that does the stuff you need for one person. For a collection of Person objects, you can define a new class if there are specific methods you need for the group (that aren't persistence related), or you can use one of the built in collection types (array).

There are a number of ways to keep the persistence (database) code separate. I use the Repository pattern. I create a class with the methods necessary to translate between my domain objects and my persistence strategy (database). Methods like:

```
getPerson(PersonCriteria $pc);
getPeople(PersonCriteria $pc);
savePerson(Person $p);
deletePerson($personID);
etc()...
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by specific methods that aren't persistence related. Can you please give me an example of a method that is, and a method that isn't persistence related? 

I had something relatively straightforward in mind, basically just a list of people that I have the permissions to see (for example those that are in my group), which is a condition that is to be formed in the constructor, based on my own user group. I don't know if you would consider this to be persistence related.

Comment: In your original example, `fetchPeople()` is persistence code, while `isVeryTall()` is not. For permissions stuff, I have had `hasPermission($permissionName)` and `getGroupNumber()` in my domain objects. And I've had permissions and group ids as options within a criteria object. The criteria object is created to communicate to your persistence layer which objects you want. The contents are usually turned into WHERE clauses, but are written in terms of the domain language, not in terms of SQL (to avoid having persistence implementation specific code in your domain). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

---

---

What you will end up doing is recreating the wheel for a lot of the pieces you need.  From associations and collections which solves the last question asked.  You will have to construct database queries from the associations and collections.  You would be creating portions of a standard library which may not be what your goal is. I would look at standard ORMs out there through the pear library or take a look at https://github.com/gabordemooij/redbean. Some others are Doctrine and Propel.

If you would like to roll your own then and want to continue with the first approach and setup a collections class to do the pagination and queries for larger batches of data using where clauses.

So that

```php
    // in a base db class
    // filters would be pagination and pairs to be used in where clause filtering
    public function fetch($filters){
        return $this->query($filters)
    }

    // ... in your child class .. using the existing join and table properties .. I would recommend moving 
    // the associations out into another class but as you can see the details of this can go on and on
    public function fetchPeople($limit = 10, $page = 1) {
        $associations = {'table'=> $this->table, 'join'=>$this->join}
            $people = $this->db->fetch(array('limit'=>$limit,'page'=>$page,$associations);
        foreach($people as $id => $person) {
            $people[$id] = new Person($person);
        }
        return $people;
    }
```